# Is there a significant connection between taking pleasure from pain and lifestyle gym going (pain from the muscle soreness the next day)?

Tags: pain, reward

Strong evidence exists of biological connections between the neurochemical pathways used for the perception of both pain and pleasure, as well as other psychological rewards (source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_and_pleasure).

Does it mean significant percentage of gym goers, go to the gym because they enjoy pain from the muscle soreness?

Comment: Do intravenous drug-users inject their drugs because they like needles in their arms? My point is that your question abstracts a single aspect of the whole and seems to apply reason to it. Is it possible that there's a larger pattern here?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.